# how to remove the quotation marks the dynamic hexadecimal value LESS

Tags: javascript, css, less

I created a function that creates a hex code to create random colors. I made the following way:

Mixin which generates code:  `_functions.less`

```
.generateRandomColor() {
    @ramColor: `"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`;
}
```

Less stylesheet that imports and uses the mixin: `style.less`

```
#container {
    > a {
        color: @red;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .2em;
        .generateRandomColor();

        border: @ramColor solid 1px;

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Generated CSS: `style.css`

```
#container > a {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.86791842 s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.86791842 s;
    -ms-transition: all linear 0.86791842 s;
    transition: all linear 0.86791842 s;
    border: "#a93bc5" solid 1px; /* **The problem is here** */
}
```

In short, I want to create the hex code for `color` but without the presentation of quotes in the compiled file (.css)

This is the HTML code where it will be used:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/less.css"/>
        <!--<script src="js/libs/less-1.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Main Title</h2>
        <h4>Less Example</h4>
        <div id="container">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the quotes?

Comment: What does all this have to do with your `.generateRandomColor()` mixin? You never use it anywhere? Please edit your question and include *valid code*.

Comment: You called your mixin with `.transition()` instead of `.generateRandomColor()`. I believe that's a typo. And from the formatting it wasn't immediately obvious that the CSS was a different file.

Comment: Has helderdarocha reason ... Edited! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixin:

```
.generateRandomColor() {
  @ramColor: `"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`;
}
```

when called in a selector generates a color within quotes:

```
.container {
   .generateRandomColor();
   color: @ramColor;
}
```

generates

```
.container {
   color: "#45ff09";
}
```

To remove the quotes from the generated CSS, simply place a `~` before the backticks to escape the string in your mixin:

```
.generateRandomColor() {
  @ramColor: ~`"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`;
}
```

Now it will generate the color correctly:

```
.container {
   color: #750ab2;
}
```

The *tilde* `~` is a equivalent to the function `e()`, which also escapes the string. This will also work. It's a matter of choice:

```
.generateRandomColor() {
     @ramColor: e(`"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`);
}
```

**UPDATE** As @seven-phases-max mentioned in the comments below, the recommended solution would be to use `color()` instead of `~` or `e()`. The color string you are generating is *in a variable* returned by a mixin which you may want to reuse and further process with color functions (`lighten()`, `fade()`, etc.). The functions `e()` and `~` are OK to generate *a final CSS string*. They would be OK in properties. Used in a variable before final CSS generation, they would still be of type *string*. So the *best solution* would be:

```
.generateRandomColor() {
     @ramColor: color(`"#" + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`);
}
```

Comment: Technically a more convenient way to convert string to a color object is `color` function. `e` creates unquoted string instead of color object so it works fine when used directly but it will fail if you try to modify it (e.g. with color functions).

Comment: Thanks for the note @seven-phases-max. I will update the answer. Since the OP is creating a color *variable* which is returned by the mixin and possibly reused, certainly `color()` should be the recommended way to do it.